# unable to insert the data values using pdo in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert

Hello I have been writing a code for uploading a file to server 
and store the values on the Mysql database 
I am able to upload the file but facing issues in inserting the values in MYSQL server

I'm retrieving the values from an HTML Form and I'm successfully able to get the values and was able to echo from the file 
Help is needed in inserting into table part of the code

```
    <?php
require "test.php";
$username=$_POST['username'];
$filename=$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'];
$language=$_POST['language'];
$comment=$_POST['comment'];

$user_id=$_POST['user_id'];
$filenames=$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'];

$category=$_POST['category'];
$subcategory=$_POST['subcategory'];
$comment=$_POST['comment'];
$language=$_POST['language'];
$duration=$_POST['duration'];


$domain ='example.com/store/upload/';
$path=$domain.$category.'/'.$filenames;
//$path=$domain.$category.'/'.$filenames;


// Where the file is going to be placed
$target_path = "upload/".$category.'/';

/* Add the original filename to our target path.
Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    echo "filename: " .  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
    echo "target_path: " .$target_path;
}



echo $filenames."<br />";
echo $domain."<br />";
echo $category."<br />";
echo $path."<br />";
echo $filename."<br />";
echo $language."<br />";
echo $comment."<br />";
echo $subcategory."<br />";
echo $duration."<br />";
echo $user_id."<br />";


// query
try{


$sql="INSERT INTO vup_file(filename,path,category,sub-category,user_id,comment,language,duration)
VALUES (:filename,:path,:category,:subcategory,:user_id,:comment,:language,:duration)";
$query=$conn->prepare($sql);

$query->execute(array(':filename'=>$filename,':path'=>$path,':category'=>$category,':subcategory'=>$subcategory,':user_id'=>$user_id,':comment'=>$comment,':language'=>$language,':duration'=>$duration));
echo 'Inserted';


}catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo 'ERROR OCCURED : '.$e->getMessage();
}


?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sub-category` column in your query, contains a hyphen. It needs to be escaped with backticks.

```
`sub-category`
```

Add `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, which would have signaled the error.

SQL is evaluating it as a mathematical problem (minus).

- Which translates to "sub" *minus* "category".

Another option you have is to simply rename your column to `sub_category` with an underscore, without the need to escape it.

---

***An insight***

If by chance your column is called `sub_category` instead of `sub-category` as shown in your query/question, then you will need to change it to `sub_category` in your query.

- Or, if it's called `subcategory`. Only you know what your column is called.